# Reftrofit and Android

Tags: android, authentication, token, retrofit, gson

I'm developing an Android application using retrofit. Now I need to authenticate with my backend server. The result of my "/token" service method's something like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "token_key_here",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 86399,
  "as:client_id": "",
  "userName": "digounet@gmail.com",
  ".issued": "Fri, 03 Jun 2016 10:46:44 GMT",
  ".expires": "Sat, 04 Jun 2016 10:46:44 GMT"
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert this result to my mojo class but no success. I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String` error. My code:

POJO Class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Token {
  @SerializedName("access_token")
  @Expose
  private String accessToken;

  @SerializedName("token_type")
  @Expose
  private String tokenType;

  @SerializedName("expires_in")
  @Expose
  private Integer expiresIn;

  @SerializedName("as:client_id")
  @Expose
  private String asClientId;

  @SerializedName("userName")
  @Expose
  private String userName;

  @SerializedName(".issued")
  @Expose
  private String issued;

  @SerializedName(".expires")
  @Expose
  private String expires;

  ... gets and meters
}
```

Login method:

```
public Usuario login(String email, String password) {
    Tokeb result = null;

    AccountService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(AccountService.class);
    Call<Object> call = service.login("password", email, password);
    try {
        String o = (String) call.execute().body();
        result = new Gson().fromJson(o, Token.class);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Retrofit convert automaticaly the json responde to object. You don't need to do new Gson().fromJson(o, Usuario.class);. But just : result = call.execute().body();

Comment: first we need see your service interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface declaration should look like

```
@POST("/Token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json"
    })
    Call<Token> getAccessToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                       @Field("username") String email,
                                       @Field("password") String password);
```

your declaration

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

login method

```
public Usuario login(String email, String password) {
       MyApiEndpointInterface apiService =
                retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface.class);
        Call<Token> call=apiService.getAccessToken("password",
                email,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
                Token token= response.body();

                Log.w("My App", token.accessToken);
                Log.w("My App", token.userName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessTokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w("My App", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

try this.